# Using ant in Netbeans problem

Tags: netbeans, ant

When I do: ant run from directory /home/me/workspace/OMI3/OperatorDisplays/
There is no problem.

In netbeans when I right click on build.xml in the same directory and select "run target", "run". Everything builds fine, but when running it seems that an evironment variable is not recognized.

Using System.getenv() I see that netbeans is running from /home/me, I want netbeans to run from /home/me/workspace/OMI3/OperatorDisplays

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to change the working directory for your project.
Go to the Properties screen of your project (`File|Project properties (yourproject)` menu or `Properties` in the project's contextual menu in the Projects tab).
Then in the `Run`category, you have a `Working directory` textfield. Put `/home/me/workspace/OMI3/OperatorDisplays` in it and it should work then.